# MouseLeftButtonDown is not fired on TreeViewItem

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:TreeView MouseLeftButtonDown="TreeView_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="this is first item"/>
    </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

---

call is not coming to TreeView_MouseLeftButtonDown event handler..
any ideas or work around?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever noticed that the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events are not fired when a Silverlight button is clicked? The reason for this is that the button handles these two events itself by overriding the OnMouseLeftButtonDown  and the OnMouseLeftButtonUp  handlers. In the OnMouseLeftButtonDown  override, the Click event is raised and the MouseLeftButtonDown event is marked as handled so it couldn't bubble in the visual tree. The OnMouseLeftButtonUp  override also marks the MouseLeftButtonUp  as handled.

This thing can be changed using the ClickMode property of the Button control. It has the following values - Hover, Press, Release. The default one is Pressed and we have already explained it. When we have ClickMode set to Release, the Click event will be raised in the OnMouseLeftButtonUp override and the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events will be handled inside the button again. If we set the ClickMode to Hover, the Click event will be raised with the MouseEnter event and we will also be able to use the mouse button events.

Comment: Did you get this from an external source? If so, it would help to add a link to the source you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is because `TreeView` handles such event as well. To override such handling, you must handle it in the code using the below:

```
treeItem.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(treeItem_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
```