# "MouseLeftButtonDown" Event not raised in TreeViewItem, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `TreeView` in WPF application. as the following.

```
<TreeView x:Name="documentOutlinePanel">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
             <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
           </Style>
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

here is the handler of the event , which exist in the Code Behind file

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,   MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // some code.
}
```

I am also handling two `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the item that can be in the `TreeView` control.

The items of the `TreeView` is bounded, by setting `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView`.

**Problem** 
The handler of the `MouseLeftButtonDown` is not executed at all. 
I set a breakpoint in the beginning of handler of this method, and the breakpoint does NOT hit at all.

But, just for notice.
the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` is triggering and I can handle it (this event does not important for me)

Can any one explain to me why the `MouseLeftButtonDown` is not fired? 
any suggestion to make it fire ?

**Update**: This question is NOT duplicated of [MouseLeftButtonDown is not fired on TreeViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851305/)

I saw that question and its answer, and it did not fit me. here is the differences

1. That question is for SliverLigth and mine for the WPF.
2. that question is Handling the `TreeView.MouseLeftButtonDown` and mine Handle the `TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown`.
3. I read the answer of that question and it did not help me in any way

Comment: possible duplicate of [MouseLeftButtonDown is not fired on TreeViewItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851305/mouseleftbuttondown-is-not-fired-on-treeviewitem)

Comment: not it is not duplicated. I saw this question and its answer and it did not fit me. here is the difference 
1- that question is for SliverLigth and mine for the WPF.
2- that question is Handling the TreeView.MouseLeftButtonDown and mine Handle the TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown.
3- I readed the answer of that question and it did not help me

any way thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thank you @qqww2, your answer may be useful, although I did not try it because I found a more pretty solution. 
I read `TreeViewItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown` source code and I figured that this event is marked as handled in this method if the `TreeViewItem` success to get the Focus.
 So I made the `TreeViewItem` object as `UnFocusable`.

```
<TreeView x:Name="documentOutlinePanel">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
          <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

This makes the `MouseLeftButtonDown` Event fire.
And inside the handler of this event, I set the `Focus` to it like this

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    // do what i want.

    item.Focusable = true;
    item.Focus();
    item.Focusable = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The `e.Handled` is set to true, because I noticed that this event occur twice,
one for the `TreeViewItem` and one for its Parent `TreeViewItem`. (because this event is bubbling event)
so at the end the always the Parent `TreeViewItem` is selected.

This worked for me in case of anyone face the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have the same problem in that question. In [`TreeViewItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/84a2d28c049dec88.html) the event is marked as handled, therefore it does not bubble up anymore.

You can overcome this by calling the code below once and registering yourself to `MouseDownEvent` for `TreeViewItem`. However be aware that this code redirects events for all `TreeViewItem`'s in your application. This may or may not be suitable for you. Also this event is fired for all mouse buttons, but you can easily check whether the clicked button is `Left` or not.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), Mouse.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonDown), true);
```

Comment: Actually, you can still hook up to `MouseLeftButtonDown` so you don't have to check which mouse button was clicked: `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, ...`